# User badges for Drupal 7 roles

Tags: 7, users

I would like to have an image/phrase appear on profile pages according to the user's role.

For instance, an editor will be identified as such, below their profile photo.

Drupal 6 had a "badges" module. But there doesn't seem to be a similar one for 7. Is there a workaround?

Comment: [Achievements](http://drupal.org/project/achievements) might be worth a look

Comment: That looks very complicated. I am looking for something which simply displays a user's role publicly.

Comment: Try User Badges module.